# Proving isomorphism between two vector spaces of homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, representation-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism

> Let $(\rho,V)$ be a representation of $G$, and we consider the following action of $G\times G$ on $\hom(V,V)$:$$\forall(g,h)\in G\times G:(g,h).\phi=\rho_g\circ\phi\circ\rho_{h^-1}$$
> Find an isomorphism between $\hom(V,V)^{G\times G}$ and $\hom(V^G,V^G)$.

First, clarification of definitions:$$\hom(V,V)^{G\times G}=\{\phi\in \hom (V,V):\forall(g,h)\in G\times G, \phi=\rho_g\circ\phi\circ\rho_{h^-1} \}$$ and $$V^G=\{v\in V:\forall g\in G,\rho_g (v)=v \}$$
Where $\rho_g$ is my notation to the linear transformation corresponding to $g$.

My attempt: I first showed that if $v\in V$, considering the pair $(g,e)\in G\times G$, I have: $$(\rho_g\circ\phi\circ\rho_e)(v)=\phi(v)$$ and therefore $$\rho_g(\phi(v))=\phi(v)$$ So $\phi(V)\subset V^G$. Now I can define $\psi:\hom(V,V)^{G\times G}\to\hom(V^G)$ by $\psi(\phi)=\phi|_{V^G}$, but I can't see if this is one-to-one\onto. I feel like there's a trick I'm missing.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: by $\mathrm{Hom}(V^G)$, do you mean $\mathrm{Hom}(V^G, V^G)$?

Comment: @StefanDawydiak yes fixed it

Comment: Similar to showing $\varphi(V) \subseteq V^G$ you also find that $\varphi(\rho_g(v) - v) = 0$, so that $\varphi$ induces a map $V_G \to V^G$ where $V_G$ denotes the maximal invariant quotient of $V$, ie $V_G = V / \langle \rho_g(v) - v \:|\: v \in V, g \in G \rangle$. So you definitely get a map $Hom(V,V)^{G\times G} \to Hom(V_G,V^G)$ which can easily be seen to be an isomorphism. However, there are cases where $V_G$ and $V^G$ are not isomorphic which might be an issue. Are $G$ and the field you are working over completely arbitrary?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I think so, but when can it fail?

Comment: If I recall correctly the main example of when things like this can fail is for finite groups where the characteristic of the field divides the order of $G$.

Comment: @StefanDawydiak we do assume it doesnt (sorry for not being specific, I asked it afterwords)

Comment: In that case they are isomorphic for any finite group $G$.

Comment: @StefanDawydiak do you happen to have the proof?

Comment: @GBA : Consider the idempotent $e =\frac{1}{|G|}  \sum_{g \in G} g$ and show that the subspace/quotient $eV \cong V/(1-e)V$ is $V^G$ as well as $V_G$. If you are only interested in this case (i.e. $G$ finite with order not divisible by characteristic), you might want to consider editing your question accordingly.